# Apple rejected app due to a crash which is not reproducing

Tags: iphone, nsdata, unrecognized-selector

Apple provided the crash logs which explains the encountered exception and reason as below:

> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
>   Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
>   Crashed Thread:  0
>   Application Specific Information:
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b4c20'

Here are the lines of code highlighted as the reason of crash after symbolicting the crash logs

```
NSXMLParser *moveParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:[str_response dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

and

```
[[UAirship shared] registerDeviceToken:[deviceToken dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] withAlias:myAlias];
```

Apple has reviewed this app on iPhone 4 and iPad 3G with iOS version 5.1 and crash happens every time to them. Whereas we are unable to reproduce the crash on any platform.
We have tried debugging on iPhone4, iPhone 3GS with iOS 5.1, iPhone 3GS with iOS 5.0, iPhone 3GS with iOS 4.3.2 but crash is not produced.

Can anyone let me know what is wrong with the code I am using?

Here is the block of code in which these lines are written.

```
NSString *str_response=(NSString *)[dic objectForKey:SuccessKey];
NSXMLParser *moveParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:[str_response dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
moveParser.delegate = self;
[moveParser parse];
[moveParser release];
```

and

```
NSString *deviceToken=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"devToken"];
[[UAirship shared] registerDeviceToken:[deviceToken dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] withAlias:myAlias];
```

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but this line: `-[__NSCFData dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector` suggests that you are calling "dataUsingEncoding:" on an object that is *already* a NSData object. I would check if there some way this could happen. "deviceToken" and "str_response" are supposed to be strings, right? Where are they assigned? Can they become NSData at some point?

Comment: Just a dumb question but it happened to me once, are you trying to reproduce this using a release build?

Comment: Yes, I have tried on both Adhoc/release build and debug build but unable to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that it has something to do with the `plist` (user defaults container). You try to register a `deviceToken` which may be `NIL` if `devToken` in `standardUserDefaults` is not set (empty or nonexistent plist-file). Try to delete all your plists in the Preferences folder and you'll probably reproduce the crash.

To solve the problem, you should check if `deviceToken` is `NIL`. If not: `registerDeviceToken`, otherwise create empty token etc.

Comment: I have tried passing nil explicitly in the device token string and in str_response string but it does not crashed.

Answer (score 0):

I think, its a clear issue of memory leak @ ** deviceToken**. Agree with @septi's description.

In exception clearly mentioned,'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent and deviceToken might be storing null value and that is creating problem.

Comment: Agree with iApple but it should be reproduced.
The problem is we are unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Hassan: Try to comment out [moveParser release]; That line could be problematic and uncertain to raise again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your string `str_response` is not in memory due to autorelease

```
NSString *str_response= ([dic objectForKey:SuccessKey] : [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[dic objectForKey:SuccessKey]] autorelease]  ?  "" );

NSXMLParser *moveParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:[str_response dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

moveParser.delegate = self;

BOOL isParsed = [moveParser parse];

if (isParsed) {

}else {

    // Parsing fail

}

[moveParser release];
```