# App rejected due to non reproducible bug: possible reasons?

Tags: ios, ipad, appstore-approval

One of our apps recently got rejected for the second time, because "We found that your app failed to launch on iPad running iOS 6.0.1, on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks".

The crash log provided by Apple starts with:

> Incident Identifier: CE8868A8-1C68-4161-91AD-DB50D3D5780B
>   CrashReporter Key:   83b816533ead866666681b87f5736242d8aac2ff
>   Hardware Model:      xxx
>   Process:         Test Skis [29192]
>   Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/890E8D9C-6A17-4EA6-9A06-5503B3D35888/Test   Skis.app/Test Skis
>   Identifier:      Test Skis
>   Version:         ??? (???)
>   Code Type:       ARM (Native)
>   Parent Process:  launchd [1]
>
> Date/Time:       2013-01-04 19:24:52.667 -0800
>   OS Version:      iOS 6.0.1 (10A523)
>   Report Version:  104
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
>   Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
>   Crashed Thread:  0

My question is not about how to fix the problem in our specific code, but a more general one: we have been unable to reproduce the crash using the same binary (making an Ad Hoc version), device, and OS version as the one Apple is supposedly using.

How is it possible that such a crash occurs on the Apple reviewer's device, and not ours? Are Apple reviewers' devices configured in a non standard way that could explain the difference?

I have found another question on Stack Overflow mentioning a similar issue, which has not been answered as well: [Apple rejected app due to a crash which is not reproducing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347091/apple-rejected-app-due-to-a-crash-which-is-not-reproducing)

Comment: The most important part of the crash report is missing, which is all the text below what you posted. Without that nobody can sadly tell you what might possibly be the problem. Please attach that and make sure it is symbolicated.

Comment: @Kerni: The complete symbolicated crash report is available at https://gist.github.com/4571561 .
However, what I am trying to understand is how it is possible that our devices do not crash, whereas Apple reviewer's do.

Comment: Another bit of info: Apple also tests apps in airplane mode (or without an internet connection to be precise), maybe that's causing the crash

Comment: This is correct in general, but when reading the crash report clearly has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I had a similar issue, app worked fine on my test device and simulator and crashed with Apple. Turned out it was to do with 'Optimisation Level' have a look in build settings, set Debug to Fastest, Smallest and see if you can reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be your ad-hoc build configuration is not identical to your release/distribution configuration in some way.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and Apple sent me a crash report to look at. I learnt how to symbolicate them, but the relevant lines of code in my app would not symbolicate. So I tried making some other changes and resubmitted, resulting in the same rejection.

Finally I requested them to send more details because I tested with two devices and on the simulator. And today I saw that they 'Developer removed from sale' and then 'Ready for sale'. So I guess my app is good to go, without any change from my side.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to instantiate a nib (name unknown, since the exception reason is missing in the crash report) and it isn't present. Make sure all nibs required by the app are actually part of the build you send to Apple.

Comment: Any Ad-Hoc build would also crash if a nib was missing, would it not?

Comment: It might or might not. Maybe there is a build problem, maybe that is only happening on a specific device type, e.g. iPad. There is not enough information available to know that from our point of view. Why don't you take the appstore binary, open it and check if all nibs that you need are actually in there? Also make sure the filenames are exactly correct, due to case sensitive filenames on the iOS devices. The `Hardware Model:` string might help, but your report says `xxx` so again nothing we can help on. The crash report is pretty clear otherwise.

Comment: I also noticed that the `Hardware Model`is not specified in the crash report sent by Apple, and I had that in mind when I asked " Are Apple reviewers' devices configured in a non standard way that could explain the difference?". The `Hardware Model`is always specified in the crash report for standard devices, isn't?

I was thinking about this possible explanation all the more that the nib name is specified using the following code:

`switch(UIDevice.currentDevice.userInterfaceIdiom) ...`

Comment: If you do that, the question is on which device types you did not test and for which types you have different nibs. Might be a start to look at :)

Comment: @Kerni:

- I just checked the binary and found the nibs that are required

- Regarding the device types the `switch(UIDevice.currentDevice.userInterfaceIdiom)`only makes a distinction between iPads and iPhones. Like I wrote, Apple mentioned that they tested using an iPad. We tested on iPad 1, 2 and 3, without being able to reproduce the crash.

Comment: Since I neither know your source, nor the binaries, nor the tests I can't give you any more hints. The crash is pretty clear that on startup instantiation of a nib is not working and an exception is thrown. Sadly the exception reason is missing in the crash report, since this would show the name of the nib. Btw. it seems that you try to present a model view controller on startup (`presentModalViewController`) in line 107 of your appDelegate and from there it crashes. Did you check that? If not, search for similar problem reports that may give a hint: `ios crash UINib instantiateWithOwner`